# How to choose which Outlook Account a Mailitem is sent from - reliably using SendUsingAccount

Tags: vba, email, outlook, client

Let's say you have several accounts attached to your Outlook client and want to be able to choose which one to send a mail from using VBA.  What do you do?  The MailItem.SendUsingAccount parameter looks the right way to do this and is recommended elsewhere [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977035/ms-access-outlook-2010-how-to-choose-which-account-to-send-email-from) or [here](http://www.slipstick.com/developer/send-using-default-or-specific-account/) or [here](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/account.htm).  However, if you apply the example in the [Developer Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869635.aspx), setting the SendUsingAccount property to valid Accounts may be impossible.  Why?

**This appears to be the answer**:  You must Dim your MailItem as an Object and **not** as an Outlook.Mailitem.  It appears that Outlook clients which have one or more Exchange Accounts do not reliably assign Accounts to a MailItem.  But, for some strange reason, if Dim As Object is used instead, the Account can be attached to that Object.  Though that Object has the Properties of a MailItem, it behaves ***better??? ... strange...***

Note:  Sending a mail on *on behalf of someone else* meets a slightly different requirement.

The following code demonstrates the **problem** and the **solution in operation**.  If there is another solution or I am missing something please let me know.

After running  the code and noting the Msgbox information, look in the Immediate Window for a summary of what is done.  The printed summary is clearer than the code which has lots of Debug.Print statements. There are 3 routines. The main test routine and 2 which get Account details from your system.

(Now posted as a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37785761/send-mail-with-specific-mailbox-defaults-from-outlook-with-pop3-or-exchange) at [vacip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4713729/vacip)'s suggestion) 
When MailItems are created they have the characteristics of the default Account, such as signatures etc. which may need changing.  If anyone knows a good way to create the initial MailItem with the characteristics of a chosen Account instead, avoiding a lot of copy/pastes/Assignments, please let me know.

```
Private Sub TestSendingAccountProblems()
'This test demonstrates the problems that occur when trying to set
' the SendingAccount of a MailItem in Outlook.
'In summary, it appears that when an Outlook client has an Exchange account attached,
' it is only possible to set the SendingAccount of a MailItem if
' THE MailItem IS CREATED AS AN OBJECT.
' A bare MailItem fails with an ERROR.
'The MailItem's SendingAccount can be set to Pop3 or Exchange, so long as the MailItem is an Object.
'It does not seem to matter whether a Pop3 or an Exchange Mailbox is active at the time.
' Choosing different mailboxes causes different signatures to be appended,(if set) but
' does not affect this SendingAccount behaviour.
'The behaviour probably is different if no Exchange account is attached - try it on your
' Outlook client if you have such a system.  Look at the listings in the Immediate Window &
' let us all know what you discover. (Cntrl-G in the VBIDE for the Immediate Window)

'All the Print statements make this and the routines it calls rather hard to read.
'You can start by just running it!

Dim appOl As Outlook.Application
Dim objNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim olMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objOutlookMsg As Object
Dim SendingAccount As Outlook.Account
Dim sOlPOP3Account As String
Dim sOlExchangeAccount As String
Dim arr() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim NumAccts As Long
Dim S As String

    Debug.Print String(100, "=")
    Set appOl = Outlook.Application
    Set objNameSpace = appOl.GetNamespace("MAPI")

'Notice that the Creation statements here are identical, this creates an Object to contain the MailItem
    Set objOutlookMsg = appOl.CreateItem(olItemType.olMailItem) 'This creates an Object to contain the MailItem
       Set olMailItem = appOl.CreateItem(olItemType.olMailItem) 'This creates a straightforward Mailitem.
'The line above creates a MailItem.
'The only difference is that olMailItem is explicitly Dimensioned as an Outlook.MailItem.

    'Write out the status
    S = objOutlookMsg.UserProperties.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.Address
    Debug.Print "objOutlookMsg was created by a user with this Address: " & S
    S = olMailItem.UserProperties.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.Address
    Debug.Print "olMailItem was created by a user with this Address:    " & S
    If objOutlookMsg.SendUsingAccount Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "objOutlookMsg.SendUsingAccount has no account specified on creation "
    Else
        Debug.Print "objOutlookMsg.SendUsingAccount.DisplayName = " & objOutlookMsg.SendUsingAccount.DisplayName
    End If
    If olMailItem.SendUsingAccount Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "olMailItem.SendUsingAccount    has no account specified on creation "
    Else
        Debug.Print "olMailItem.SendUsingAccount.DisplayName    =  " & olMailItem.SendUsingAccount.DisplayName
    End If

    'Collect the Account DisplayNames
'The strings here must be the Account Name.  To see these, do this:
'Outlook Ribbon: File>Account Settings>AccountSettings-Name column.
' You can enter your own accounts here, but it is easier to let it fetch them all for you using the code below.
'    sOlPOP3Account = "my.name@POP3server.com"
'    sOlExchangeAccount = "my.name@ExchangeServer.com"
'ReDim arr(1 To 2)
'    NumAccts = 2
'    arr(1) = sOlPOP3Account
'    arr(2) = sOlExchangeAccount
'
    'Automatically includes up to 10 accounts
    NumAccts = 0
    For i = 1 To 10
'   Choose all accounts or just one of these: (don't leave both exposed)
        S = GetAccountNameOfType(vbNullString)      'This will get all accounts that are accessible from the Outlook client'
'        S = GetAccountNameOfType("POP3")            'This will get only the Pop3 accounts that are accessible from the Outlook client
        If S = vbNullString Then Exit For
        NumAccts = NumAccts + 1
ReDim Preserve arr(1 To NumAccts)
        arr(NumAccts) = S
    Next i

    For i = 1 To NumAccts
        S = GetAccountType(arr(i), i)
        On Error Resume Next
        Set SendingAccount = appOl.Session.Accounts.Item(arr(i))
        If ERR <> 0 Or SendingAccount Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print String(20, "-") & vbLf & S & " account could NOT be set to variable SendingAccount. The " & S & " account has .DisplayName = " & arr(i)
        Else
            Debug.Print String(20, "+") & vbLf & S & " account WAS          set to variable SendingAccount. The " & S & " account has .DisplayName = " & arr(i)
        End If
        'Works fine in all scenarios tested using an Outlook client with an Exchange account attached.
      Object   ' The Watch Window shows .SendingAccount = chosen Account of Type = Account/Account
        On Error Resume Next
        Set objOutlookMsg.SendUsingAccount = SendingAccount
        If ERR <> 0 Then
            Debug.Print "objOutlookMsg.SendUsingAccount was NOT SET.  The Error number is " & ERR & ", Description: " & ERR.Description & " - look at what was printed above for status of the SendingAccount (or look above/check in the Watch window if stepping through.)"
        Else
            Debug.Print "objOutlookMsg.SendUsingAccount was set successfully to: " & objOutlookMsg.SendUsingAccount.DisplayName
        End If
        On Error Resume Next
        'Fails .in all scenarios tested using an Outlook client with an Exchange account attached.
        ' The Watch Window shows .SendingAccount = chosen Account of Type = Account/Account
        Set olMailItem.SendUsingAccount = SendingAccount
        If ERR <> 0 Then
            Debug.Print "   olMailItem.SendUsingAccount was NOT SET.  The Error number is " & ERR & ", Description: " & ERR.Description & " (the SendingAccount may be 'Nothing' - look above/check in the Watch window.)"
        Else
            Debug.Print "   olMailItem.SendUsingAccount was set successfully to: " & olMailItem.SendUsingAccount.DisplayName
        End If
    Next i


'Clean up
Set appOl = Nothing
Set objNameSpace = Nothing
Set olMailItem = Nothing
Set objOutlookMsg = Nothing
Set SendingAccount = Nothing
End Sub'Started with code from:
'https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7a8bed41-a28f-41aa-bbc5-bfb8057a7bc4/stuck-on-how-to-get-sendusingaccount-to-work?forum=isvvba
'revised to create 2 functions that return the current account's status and displays all the accounts at one time, neatly lined up
'and another that finds accounts of a specified type.
Private Function GetAccountType(sForDisplayName As String, _
                                Optional lDisplayMessage As Long) As String
' Returns the type of the account named sForDisplayName.
' Shows a message listing all the accounts and types only if lDisplayMessage is = +1 or -1.
    'NOTE: If changes to the email accounts have been made in Outlook _
     then must close Outlook and Re-Open before any of this works properly.

Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objNameSpace As Object
Dim strAccountType As String
Dim strOlNameAccountType As String
Dim Account As Outlook.Account
Dim i As Long
Dim HitNum As Long
Dim bAcc As Boolean         'Determines whether the Account Type or the Account name of the next Account of Given Type is returned
Dim S As String             'Scratch string
Dim S1 As String            'Scratch string
Static LenStr As Long       'The Length of the display string in the MsgBox window
Static lGT As Long          'Account number within NumAccts that we have reached
Static sLstAcType As String 'The last Account type that was specified in sGetNextAccountOfType
Static NumAccts As Long     'The number of Accounts

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objNameSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    LenStr = 40

DO_AGAIN:                                            'Returns to here if the account names are found to be long
    S = vbNullString

    For i = 1 To objNameSpace.Session.Accounts.Count
        Set Account = objNameSpace.Session.Accounts.Item(i)
        If Len(Account.DisplayName) + 10 + 1 > LenStr Then
            LenStr = Len(Account.DisplayName) + 10 + 1
            If LenStr > 86 Then LenStr = 86: GoTo GET_ON_WITH_IT
            GoTo DO_AGAIN
        End If
GET_ON_WITH_IT:
        With Account
            S1 = Right(String(LenStr - 10, "-") & Account.DisplayName, LenStr - 10)
            Select Case .AccountType
            Case 0
               strAccountType = "Exchange"
                strOlNameAccountType = Right(String(10, "-") & "olExchange", 10)    'Watch Window shows olExchange
            Case 2
                strAccountType = "POP3"
                strOlNameAccountType = Right(String(10, "-") & "olPop3", 10)        'Watch Window shows olExchange
            Case Else
                strAccountType = "Not POP3 or Exchange Account"
                strOlNameAccountType = Right(String(10, "-") & "Not P3/Exg", 10)    'Don't know what Watch Window shows!
            End Select
            S = S & i & "-" & Right(String(LenStr + 1, "-") & S1 & vbTab & "-" & strOlNameAccountType, LenStr + 1) & vbLf
            If Abs(lDisplayMessage) = 1 Then _
                Debug.Print Replace(i & "-" & Right(String(LenStr + 1, "-") & S1 & vbTab & "-" & strOlNameAccountType, LenStr + 1), "-", " ")
            If .DisplayName = sForDisplayName Then
                GetAccountType = strAccountType
            End If
        End With
    Next i
    NumAccts = i - 1
    'Only displays when lDisplayMessage = +1 or -1.  Defaults to not displaying if lDisplayMessage is is unset.
    If Abs(lDisplayMessage) = 1 Then _
    MsgBox String(86, "-") & vbLf & "List of all Email Accounts on " & Environ$("computername") & ":" & vbLf & _
           Left("- Account " & String(LenStr - Len("- Account " & vbTab & "Type"), "-"), LenStr) & vbTab & "Type" & vbLf & _
           S & vbLf & _
           String(86, "-")

    Set objNameSpace = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing
    Set Account = Nothing

End Function

Private Function GetAccountNameOfType(sTypeToGet As String) As String
' Gets the next account of the given type.
' Called repeatedly with the same sTypeToGet returns a Null string on the last found (or if none are).
' If the VBIDE is reset, it starts again at the beginning.
    'NOTE: If changes to the email accounts have been made in Outlook _
     then must close Outlook and Re-Open before any of this works properly.

Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objNameSpace As Object
Dim strAccountType As String
Dim Account As Outlook.Account
Dim i As Long
Dim HitNum As Long
Dim bInit As Boolean        'It is an initialisation run
Static lGT As Long          'Account number within NumAccts that we have reached
Static sLstAcType As String 'The last Account type that was specified in sTypeToGet
Static NumAccts As Long     'The number of Accounts

    If NumAccts > 0 Then
        lGT = lGT + 1                   'Get the next hit
    Else
        bInit = True                    'Be sure to count the accounts on the first run
        lGT = 1                         'and when the last exit resulted in no hit
    End If

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objNameSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    For i = 1 To objNameSpace.Session.Accounts.Count
        Set Account = objNameSpace.Session.Accounts.Item(i)
        With Account
            Select Case .AccountType
            Case 0
               strAccountType = "Exchange"
            Case 2
                strAccountType = "POP3"
            Case Else
                strAccountType = "Not POP3 or Exchange Account"
            End Select
            If UCase(strAccountType) = UCase(sTypeToGet) Or sTypeToGet = vbNullString Then
                HitNum = HitNum + 1
                If HitNum = lGT Then
                    GetAccountNameOfType = Account.DisplayName
                    If Not bInit Then
                        If sTypeToGet <> vbNullString Then NumAccts = HitNum
                        GoTo FOUNDIT
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next i
    If Not bInit Then
        If GetAccountNameOfType = vbNullString Then
            NumAccts = 0
        Else
            NumAccts = i - 1
        End If
    Else
        NumAccts = i - 1        'Always keep a count when initialising
    End If
FOUNDIT:
    sLstAcType = sTypeToGet

    Set objNameSpace = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing
    Set Account = Nothing

End Function



'https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7a8bed41-a28f-41aa-bbc5-bfb8057a7bc4/stuck-on-how-to-get-sendusingaccount-to-work?forum=isvvba
    'was heavily adapted to create 2 functions that return the current account's status and displays all the accounts at one time, neatly lined up
    'and another that finds accounts of a specified type.
    Private Function GetAccountType(sForDisplayName As String, _
                                    Optional lDisplayMessage As Long) As String
    ' Returns the type of the account named sForDisplayName.
    ' Shows a message listing all the accounts and types only if lDisplayMessage is = +1 or -1.
        'NOTE: If changes to the email accounts have been made in Outlook _
         then must close Outlook and Re-Open before any of this works properly.

Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objNameSpace As Object
Dim strAccountType As String
Dim strOlNameAccountType As String
Dim Account As Outlook.Account
Dim i As Long
Dim HitNum As Long
Dim bAcc As Boolean         'Determines whether the Account Type or the Account name of the next Account of Given Type is returned
Dim S As String             'Scratch string
Dim S1 As String            'Scratch string
Static LenStr As Long       'The Length of the display string in the MsgBox window
Static lGT As Long          'Account number within NumAccts that we have reached
Static sLstAcType As String 'The last Account type that was specified in sGetNextAccountOfType
Static NumAccts As Long     'The number of Accounts

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objNameSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    LenStr = 40

DO_AGAIN:                                            'Returns to here if the account names are found to be long
    S = vbNullString

    For i = 1 To objNameSpace.Session.Accounts.Count
        Set Account = objNameSpace.Session.Accounts.Item(i)
        If Len(Account.DisplayName) + 10 + 1 > LenStr Then
            LenStr = Len(Account.DisplayName) + 10 + 1
            If LenStr > 86 Then LenStr = 86: GoTo GET_ON_WITH_IT
            GoTo DO_AGAIN
        End If
GET_ON_WITH_IT:
        With Account
            S1 = Right(String(LenStr - 10, "-") & Account.DisplayName, LenStr - 10)
            Select Case .AccountType
            Case 0
               strAccountType = "Exchange"
                strOlNameAccountType = Right(String(10, "-") & "olExchange", 10)    'Watch Window shows olExchange
            Case 2
                strAccountType = "POP3"
                strOlNameAccountType = Right(String(10, "-") & "olPop3", 10)        'Watch Window shows olExchange
            Case Else
                strAccountType = "Not POP3 or Exchange Account"
                strOlNameAccountType = Right(String(10, "-") & "Not P3/Exg", 10)    'Don't know what Watch Window shows!
            End Select
            S = S & i & "-" & Right(String(LenStr + 1, "-") & S1 & vbTab & "-" & strOlNameAccountType, LenStr + 1) & vbLf
            If Abs(lDisplayMessage) = 1 Then _
                Debug.Print Replace(i & "-" & Right(String(LenStr + 1, "-") & S1 & vbTab & "-" & strOlNameAccountType, LenStr + 1), "-", " ")
            If .DisplayName = sForDisplayName Then
                GetAccountType = strAccountType
            End If
        End With
    Next i
    NumAccts = i - 1
    'Only displays when lDisplayMessage = +1 or -1.  Defaults to not displaying if lDisplayMessage is is unset.
    If Abs(lDisplayMessage) = 1 Then _
    MsgBox String(86, "-") & vbLf & "List of all Email Accounts on " & Environ$("computername") & ":" & vbLf & _
           Left("- Account " & String(LenStr - Len("- Account " & vbTab & "Type"), "-"), LenStr) & vbTab & "Type" & vbLf & _
           S & vbLf & _
           String(86, "-")

    Set objNameSpace = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing
    Set Account = Nothing

End Function

Private Function GetAccountNameOfType(sTypeToGet As String) As String
' Gets the next account of the given type.
' Called repeatedly with the same sTypeToGet returns a Null string on the last found (or if none are).
' If the VBIDE is reset, it starts again at the beginning.
    'NOTE: If changes to the email accounts have been made in Outlook _
     then must close Outlook and Re-Open before any of this works properly.

Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objNameSpace As Object
Dim strAccountType As String
Dim Account As Outlook.Account
Dim i As Long
Dim HitNum As Long
Dim bInit As Boolean        'It is an initialisation run
Static lGT As Long          'Account number within NumAccts that we have reached
Static sLstAcType As String 'The last Account type that was specified in sTypeToGet
Static NumAccts As Long     'The number of Accounts

    If NumAccts > 0 Then
        lGT = lGT + 1                   'Get the next hit
    Else
        bInit = True                    'Be sure to count the accounts on the first run
        lGT = 1                         'and when the last exit resulted in no hit
    End If

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objNameSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    For i = 1 To objNameSpace.Session.Accounts.Count
        Set Account = objNameSpace.Session.Accounts.Item(i)
        With Account
            Select Case .AccountType
            Case 0
               strAccountType = "Exchange"
            Case 2
                strAccountType = "POP3"
            Case Else
                strAccountType = "Not POP3 or Exchange Account"
            End Select
            If UCase(strAccountType) = UCase(sTypeToGet) Or sTypeToGet = vbNullString Then
                HitNum = HitNum + 1
                If HitNum = lGT Then
                    GetAccountNameOfType = Account.DisplayName
                    If Not bInit Then
                        If sTypeToGet <> vbNullString Then NumAccts = HitNum
                        GoTo FOUNDIT
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next i
    If Not bInit Then
        If GetAccountNameOfType = vbNullString Then
            NumAccts = 0
        Else
            NumAccts = i - 1
        End If
    Else
        NumAccts = i - 1        'Always keep a count when initialising
    End If
FOUNDIT:
    sLstAcType = sTypeToGet

    Set objNameSpace = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing
    Set Account = Nothing

End Function
```

Here is a sample of the output from running this program on an Outlook Client that has 2 POP3 and 1 Exchange account attached to it:

```
    ''====================================================================================================
''objOutlookMsg was created by a user with this Address: /o=ExchangeLabs/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (lotsofcharacter)/cn=Recipients/cn=longhexnumberisplacedherefollowe-dname
''olMailItem was created by a user with this Address:    /o=ExchangeLabs/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (lotsofcharacter)/cn=Recipients/cn=longhexnumberisplacedherefollowe-dname
''objOutlookMsg.SendUsingAccount has no account specified on creation 
''olMailItem.SendUsingAccount    has no account specified on creation 
''olMailItem.SendUsingAccount    has no account specified on creation
''1     joey.bloggs@POP3server.com         olPop3
''2 jane.blogginnss@POP3server.com         olPop3
''3           X@exchangeserver.com     olExchange
''++++++++++++++++++++
''POP3 account WAS          set to variable SendingAccount. The POP3 account has .DisplayName = joey.bloggs@POP3server.com
''objOutlookMsg.SendUsingAccount was set successfully to: joey.bloggs@POP3server.com
''   olMailItem.SendUsingAccount was NOT SET.  The Error number is 91, Description: Object variable or With block variable not set (the SendingAccount may be 'Nothing' - look above/check in the Watch window.)
''++++++++++++++++++++
''POP3 account WAS          set to variable SendingAccount. The POP3 account has .DisplayName = jane.blogginnss@POP3server.com
''objOutlookMsg.SendUsingAccount was set successfully to: jane.blogginnss@POP3server.com
''   olMailItem.SendUsingAccount was NOT SET.  The Error number is 91, Description: Object variable or With block variable not set (the SendingAccount may be 'Nothing' - look above/check in the Watch window.)
''++++++++++++++++++++
''Exchange account WAS          set to variable SendingAccount. The Exchange account has .DisplayName = X@exchangeserver.com
''objOutlookMsg.SendUsingAccount was set successfully to: X@exchangeserver.com
''   olMailItem.SendUsingAccount was NOT SET.  The Error number is 91, Description: Object variable or With block variable not set (the SendingAccount may be 'Nothing' - look above/check in the Watch window.)
```

Comment: Thought I'd throw [my solution](https://gist.github.com/asheroto/ed31bb13a0eb59cef22abd247eea89f3) into the mix.

Answer (score 1):

With Exchange accounts only, I reproduced your results. The problem could be in your code.

I can set SendUsingAccount on mailitem.

```
Sub sendFromEachAccount()

    Dim olAccounts As Accounts
    Dim olMsg As mailItem
    Dim i As Long

    Dim accountCount As Long
    accountCount = Session.Accounts.count

    For i = 1 To accountCount

        Set olMsg = CreateItem(olMailItem)

        Debug.Print "Account: " & i & ": " & "DisplayName: " & Session.Accounts(i).DisplayName

        With olMsg
            .SendUsingAccount = Session.Accounts.Item(i)
            .Display
        End With

    Next i

ExitRoutine:
    Set olMsg = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this.  You say you reproduced my results, which is not surprising to me but is certainly reassuring.  However, you then say that the problem may be in my code and give an example where you (presumably successfully) set .SendUsingAcccount in an environment where there are only Exchange accounts.  This is nice but it does not appear to solve the problem in the case where there are also POP3 accounts.  Am I missing something here?  Are you actually saying that there is no problem when there are mixed accounts?  Or did you NOT reproduce the problem that was mentioned?

Comment: For an Exchange-only setup your code indicates mailitem has a problem. That is a "false positive" result as my code works. There is no problem setting .SendUsingAccount on mailitem in my Exchange-only setup.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies.  You get the same error from_my_code when you run it even though you are using only Exchange accounts.  I'll have to investigate.  I'm currently migrating my VBA code base to VB.Net so it may be a while before I respond to your new info.  The workaround works for the moment in VBA.  (Pity microsoft no longer provides the VBA->VB.Net converter...I'm having to write one in VB.NET to migrate my stuff!)

Comment: I was facing the same issue as the OP with some code that used to work in previous versions of MS Office. Your code, on the other hand, works in MS Office 365 as of the time of writing.