# Sending email from different account VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Trying to send emails using VBA however it keeps sending from my personal email address despite best efforts. Please can someone advise how to send from secondary email address?

```
Sub Send_Mail()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Send_Mail")
Dim I As Integer

Dim OA As Object
Dim msg As Object

Set OA = CreateObject("outlook.application")
Set OutAccount = OA.Session.Accounts.Item(2)

Dim last_row As Integer
last_row = Application.CountA(sh.Range("A:A"))

For I = 2 To last_row
    Set msg = OA.CreateItem(0)
    msg.SendUsingAccount = OutAccount
    msg.To = sh.Range("B" & I).Value
    msg.cc = sh.Range("D" & I).Value
    msg.Subject = sh.Range("E" & I).Value
    msg.body = sh.Range("F" & I).Value
            
    If sh.Range("G" & I).Value <> "" Then
        msg.attachments.Add sh.Range("G" & I).Value
            
End If
    
msg.send
    
sh.Range("H" & I).Value = "Sent"

Next I

MsgBox "All emails sent successfully"

End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS Access / Outlook 2010 - how to choose which account to send email from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977035/ms-access-outlook-2010-how-to-choose-which-account-to-send-email-from)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send email from a specific Outlook account using Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55360867/how-to-send-email-from-a-specific-outlook-account-using-excel)

Answer (score 0):

You can use .From to set the email account that you want to send it from.

```
strFrom = Name & "<" & Email & ">"
msg.From = strFrom
```

Comment: There is no .From. There is `.SendUsingAccount` and `.SentOnBehalfOfName`.

Comment: I'm using the Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem for a list of mailitem properties. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977035/ms-access-outlook-2010-how-to-choose-which-account-to-send-email-from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64264085/using-other-mail-account-by-sending-mail-from-excel-to-outlook